# Simplest syntax for a TypeScript lambda that returns an object literal

Tags: typescript

Consider the JavaScript function:

```
function(o) { return o.a; }
```

In TypeScript, the following shorthand is equivalent:

```
o => o.a
```

Is there a way to apply this shorthand to the following function?

```
function(o) { return { a: o.a, b: o.b }; }
```

The obvious transformation does not work as the opening brace (`{`) is interpreted as indicating a block is required:

```
o => { a: o.a, b: o.b }                // doesn't work

o => { return { a: o.a, b: o.b }; }    // works
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There isn't a way to make the grammar interpret the { as an object literal rather than a block statement in this context, but you can use parentheses to force it to be interpreted as an expression:

```
var x = (t) => ({ n: t });
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I suspected that was the case but wanted to be clear. I imagine this may trip some folks up. The error message simply states that a `;` is expected.

Comment: Updated answer - you can still use =>

Comment: Nice! Thanks for coming back and updating your answer.

Comment: Makes sense, but I didn't think of it. I often get this error and thought there should be a better option than writing {return {...};}. Thanks!

Comment: Note that by now you can also use deconstruction to make the proposed a,b lambda even smaller: `({a,b}) => ({a,b})`

Comment: @Bram , you said "deconstruction", do you have a link on that? I could only find information on ["destructuring"](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html) , and it looks like you're using "destructuring" for the `a,b` **parameters** passed into your lambda. It also looks like you're using ["object literal property value shorthand"](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand) to create the `{a,b}` **return value** from your lambda. Could you correct me if I'm wrong, and/or send me a link to "deconstruction"?

Comment: You're totally right, destructuring is what I was referring to!